# rename files in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I've a number of files in unix timestamp that are being moved to a Windows fileserver.

We need to rename these files in a batch to a readable date format: YYYYMMDDHHMISS

I already have the convert function from unix timestamp to the required format.
My issue is that I have to find a way to read the folder content (xp_cmdshell) and pass these values to the function and after that rename the files with its according format.
1. I know how to get the readable format
2. I can read the folder contents
3. The combination of these to and to rename to file is the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: See http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/303040-renaming-multiple-files-by-adding-date-time-stamp and http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=66362.0

Comment: What is your current code? Have you tried `for` command?

Comment: The file name has the unix timestamp format. F.i. the name of the file is 1081277409 and I should rename the file to 2004-04-0616:50:09.000. I have the solution for the conversion. But the automatically renaming is the issue.I have to do this for 4000 files automatically.

Comment: try some code and come back with a more specific question. Hint, try `FOR %a in (*) DO @echo call renameTS %a`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include `:` in a Windows file name as you suggest in your comment. I suggest a format like 
`2004-04-06_16-50-09.000`

I know you say you have code for the time stamp conversion, but I have written a handy [JScript/batch hybrid utility called getTimestamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847) that should make the job easy.

Assuming you have getTimestamp.bat in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere in your path, then the following batch script should do the trick:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd "pathToYourFiles"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"'
) do (
  call getTimestamp -d %%F000 -f {yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}_{hh}-{nn}-{ss}.{fff} -r name
  ren "%%F" "!name!"
)
popd
```

If the new name format is not to your liking, read the documentation built into getTimestamp.bat: It has enough options that you should be able to get exactly what you want.

***Note:***

The code above will only work if all the file names are from year 2002 onward. If you have names pre-dating 2002, then I suggest using `findstr "^[0-9]*$"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach your 3 having used xp_cmdshell, you will have a one column table with the list of files in it (i assume you have run a `dir` command to get the name of files).

Declare a cursor for the table, and for each of the records, calculate the correct name and use xp_cmdshell to execute a rename of the file.

See [here](http://www.siccolo.com/articles/sqlscripts/create-sql-to-mass_rename-files.html) for a example.

Anyway, you can do it, but sql server is not the place to do mass file rename (just my opinion, any of the other answers is more adecuate for the task).